# jQuery when function does not evaluate the deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, deferred

I'm having an issue with Jquery deferred object. I'm creating a promise inside a function that will do a ajax call and saving a data to server.
I know jQuery ajax having a predefine deferred object.

```
var AddCodes = function(XML ){
    var def = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "webservicename.asmx/SaveCode",
        data: "{" + XML + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            def.resolve();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            def.reject();
        }
    });

   return def.promise();
}
```

then I'm evaluating the function like this.

```
$.when(AddCodes(XML)).then(function(){
    processData();
}
```

If the AddCodes() function is executed successfully only I'm calling another function to insert some data into database. Because both are dependent function.

The problem is when function doesn't evaluate deferred `object. processData()` never worked. I'm using deferred first time to my project. Please help me to sort this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) says that `$.when()` accepts both deferred objects (created with `$.Deferred()` **and** plain objects, which are considered as already fulfilled promises.

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.

But `AddCodes()` doesn't return anything. If you return your deferred object (`def`) this should work.

So, if you change your code to

```
var AddCodes = function(XML ){
    var def = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        ....
    });

    return def.promise();
}
```

you should be ok. Note that this is just like [the first example here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

Comment: I didn't copy the correct code. now I edited code. I already used return. but not working.